# CKEditor online builder differs from github dev build.sh

Tags: ckeditor

It seems that the online builder here: http://ckeditor.com/builder  produces a different minified file than the git repo using the process as outlined here : docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_build

I have synced my local git clone to [4.5.8]. 
When I run /dev/builder/build.sh. the output ckeditor.js file starts with

```
(function(){window.CKEDITOR&&window.CKEDITOR.dom||(window.CKEDITOR||(window.CKEDITOR=function(){var a=/
```

which looks the same as the one stored in the releases project:
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases/blob/master/ckeditor.js

But the first line of the same file generated by the online builder starts like this :

```
(function(){if(window.CKEDITOR&&window.CKEDITOR.dom)return;window.CKEDITOR||(window.CKEDITOR=function(){var a=/
```

(Note the if/return instead of ||)
Functionally this is equivalent, but I have no idea if there are actual functional differences deeper in the files.

My question is : Is there a way to configure the dev/build.sh to use the same minifier as the online tool -- I want to integrate a local change, but the diff looks like my change is larger than it is.

Comment: from https://github.com/ckeditor/ckbuilder, I've learned that the --preprocess-core flag is used, but it's still impossible to know what the appropriate use would be.